# New table row in primefaces repeat

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a list that I want to display in table along with radio buttons. UI Requirement is that there are grouped in table, 3 in a row. My idea was to use `<p:repeat>` and `<p:fragment>` on every third index to close last `<tr>` and open a new one.

Code is/was:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <p:repeat
            value="#{bean.arrayInBean}"
            var="value" varStatus="status">
                <td>
                    <span title="#{value.description}"> 
                    <input type="radio" value="#{value.code}"
                        name="valueName" /> #{value.code}
                    </span>
                </td>
            <p:fragment rendered="#{(status.index + 1) % 3 eq 0}">
                </tr>
                <tr>
            </p:fragment>
        </p:repeat>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Unfortunately i get `Error Parsing...The element type "p:fragment" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</p:fragment>"`

Comment: Why you won't you use `p:dataTable` instead?

Comment: @JorgeCampos I'm open for every solution (I think I considered p:dataTable), but wouldn't I run into same problem again? Multiple items in same row? If you have a snippet or a link that would help me implement it....

Comment: This is not related to a `p:repeat` and not to a `p:fragment`. It is invalid xml (which xhtml should comply with).

Comment: Use the `p:dataGrid` component and set the number of columns to 3, see an example here: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataGrid.xhtml the internal panels you can use CSS to format the way you need